# BroadcastReceiver for Google-Cloud-Messaging-Service is not triggered

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I've programmed a server-application which should send Notifications via the "Google Cloud Messagin Service" (GCM) to registered devices. So far everything works fine on the server-side. This is the response message from google:

```
{"multicast_id":8327537504427777382,
"success":1,
 "failure":0,
 "canonical_ids":0,
 "results":[
 {"message_id":"0:1380212213392874%40dd3702f9fd7ecd"
 }
 ]
 }
```

My problem is that the device never receives this message.
I've double checked all the values especially the gcmId and the api-key from my google api.
They seem to be alright.

I don't understand why my BroadcastReceiver is never triggered. Could it be that i missconfigured something in the AndroidManifest.xml?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<permission android:name="berghegger.newsreader.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="berghegger.newsreader.permission.C2D_Message" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <receiver 
        android:name="berghegger.newsreader.gcm.MobilePushReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE">
                <category android:name="berghegger.newsreader" />
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Best regards

Robert

The BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class MobilePushReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("MobilePushReceiver", "onReceive()");
    Toast.makeText(context, "received a push!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}
```

Comment: The manifest seems correct (assuming the package of your app is `berghegger.newsreader`). Are you sure the receiver is not triggered? Did you try to debug the app and put a breakpoint in `onReceive`?

Comment: berghegger.newsreader is the package of my app. All I did was a simple Log.d("MobilePushReceiver", "onReceive()"); I will try it with a breakpoint.

Comment: Ok I've tried it and it is not reaching onReceive(). I've also registered the "android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED"-action within the intent-filter to test if the broadcastReceiver is working. The onReceive method gets triggered whenever i toggle the bluetoth on or off. Also I'm developing with Android 2.3.6. - I hope this is not the issue.

Comment: Can you post your broadcast receiver?

Comment: I added the broadcast receiver to my question

Answer (score 0):

Today I tried the app with Android 4.3 and everything works fine. The Notifications arrive as they should. So it is not a programming issue. I thought about the dependencies i'm using:

- Action-Bar-Sherlock 4.4 + It's own version of the Android-Support-Library (v4)
- The Google-Play-Services-Library (Revision 12)

Could there be the problem?